# absolute positioned div's relative positioned sibling has moved above

Tags: css

Below I have an absolute positioned div#in that resides within a relative position div#out. div#in is pulled out of the flow and stretched over div#out by coordinate top,bottom,left,right being set to 0.
This is fine, but what I don't understand is if I give div#sibling postion:relative it appears above the div#in.

I've checked the z-index of all divs and they are "auto" which I believe is the same as zero.

I am using Version 45.0.2454.101 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) but believe this is a just a misunderstanding on my part,not a browsers problem.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
<style>
    #out { 
        border: 1px solid red;
        background: red;
        position: relative;
    }
    #in { 
        border: 1px solid green;
        background: green;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    #sibling{
        position:relative;
    }
</style>

<div id="out"> 
    This is the outer div<br>
    position relative

    <div id="in">inner div position absolute</div>
    <div id="other">other div position static </div>
    <div id="sibling">sibling position relative </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's happening because your in has absolute position + you have set top, bottom, right, left e'thing to be 0. Remove these lines and add float:left

Comment: Why not set the z-index to your `in` element to be greater than `0`?

Comment: @tanjir I thought by setting div#in coordinates to top,bottom,left it would cover all elements in div#out with the execeptions on abosolute elements. div#relative does not have any coordinates. I thought that relative without coords behaves like a static element, but maybe I'm wrong here.

Comment: @A.Sharma I understand I can fix this with z-index but I'm trying to understand the behavior. Another point of interest is if you place elem div#sibling above div#inner in the html, it will move under the stretched div#in. This is the behavior I was expecting in its current position.

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp):

> An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element
>   with a lower stack order.
>   Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed).

When you give position relative to the `#sibling`, it is appeared above the `#in` because of your html order.

Solutions:

Give more z-index to the `#in`

CSS

```
#in { 
        border: 1px solid green;
        background: green;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index:10;
    }

#sibling{
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="out"> 
    This is the outer div<br>
    position relative

    <div id="in">inner div position absolute</div>
    <div id="other">other div position static </div>
    <div id="sibling">sibling position relative </div>
</div>
```

or

CSS

```
#in { 
        border: 1px solid green;
        background: green;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

#sibling{
   //you can remove position
   //position:relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="out"> 
    This is the outer div<br>
    position relative
    <div id="sibling">sibling position relative </div>
    <div id="in">inner div position absolute</div>
    <div id="other">other div position static </div>
</div>
```